# Proof of $\left |\frac{\sin(n+1/2)t}{\sin{t/2}}-\frac{\sin{nt}}{\tan{t/2}}\right| \leq 1$

Tags: analysis

I need help to proof
$$\left |\frac{\sin(n+1/2)t}{\sin{t/2}}-\frac{\sin{nt}}{\tan{t/2}}\right| \leq 1$$

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: In the direction of chenbai, you should get that $|cos(nt)| \leq 1$ as your final step.

Answer (score 1):

hint:$\left |\dfrac{\sin(n+1/2)t}{\sin{t/2}}-\dfrac{\sin{nt}}{\tan{t/2}}\right|=\left |\dfrac{\sin(n+1/2)t-\sin{nt}\cos{t/2}}{\sin{t/2}}\right|$

Comment: Thank you, I tried the following:
$$\left |\dfrac{\sin(n+1/2)t}{\sin{t/2}}-\dfrac{\sin{nt}}{\tan{t/2}}\right|=\left |\dfrac{\sin(n+1/2)t-\sin{nt}\cos{t/2}}{\sin{t/2}}\right|=\left|\dfrac{1/2 \sin((N+ 1/2)t)- 1/2 \sin((N- 1/2 )t)}{\sin (t/2)}\right|$$ with $\sin x \cos y = 1/2 \sin (x-y) +1/2 \sin (x+y)$, but now I am stuck...

Comment: $sin(x+y)=sin(x)cos(y)+cos(y)sin(x)$,can you go on this way?

Comment: Hi, now I got it. For other readers: you mean
$\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y +\sin y \cos x$